# how to remove other row based on selected row value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i try to remove all row that has not equal to "acctname" and once I click 1 row nothing happen ? im using check box and function to get the value of selected row.

```
var TableExcess;
    $(function () {
       TableExcess = $('#PaymentExcess').DataTable({
            "scrollY": '50vh',
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            //"searching": false,
            "ajax": "@Url.Action("GetPaymentExcess", "payable")",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='addavailable(" + full.Id + ", " + full.AvailableAmount + ", \"" + full.AccountName + "\", this.checked)'>"
                    }
                },
                { "data": "Id" },
                { "data": "AccountName" },
                { "data": "PaidAmount" },
                { "data": "AvailableAmount" },
            ]
        });
    });

function addavailable(id, amount, acctname, isChecked)
    {
       
        var filteredData = TableExcess
        .column( 2 )
        .data()
        .filter( function ( value, index ) {
            return TableExcess.row(value).data()[2] != acctname;
        })
        TableExcess.rows( filteredData )
        .remove()
        .draw();
    }
```